# How can I find repeat strings in an array of strings using php?

Tags: php, arrays

to start of, I am not looking for array_unique().
say I have an array of strings such as:

```
"aok-e","aok-8","aok-c"
```

I want to find and remove the "aok-" from all of those values.
note: I want to do this without initially knowing that value i.e. "aok-"

Comment: and what have you tried ?

Comment: Artificial Intelligence, In general :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm aware of str_replace.
what I'm trying to accomplish is finding out that "aok-" is a repeating value in the array

Comment: Unless you know what you are looking for, at least a hint of it such as a hyphen "-" or a part of a string, there is no way to do this easily. You're going into pattern recognition which is a form of AI... good luck if thats the case!

Answer (score 0):

This seems a simple case of array_map

```
$items = array_map(function($a){
    return str_replace(['aok-', 'kj', 'l9'], '', $a);
}, ["aok-e","aok-8","aok-c", "kjCl9", "kjDl9"]);
```

Yields

```
['e', '8', 'c', 'C', 'D']
```

Adapt as needed!

---

Since you made an edit, here's my thought

You absolutely need something to work on at a base. If what you want is to  get only the information after the "-", then it can still be done the same way. But doing so artificial intelligent search on your array is practically impossible, you're going into something very very very complex.

Answer (score 0):

1) Split array using `foreach` loop

2) Remove or replace the string as you want using `if..else` condition

3) To replace string use `str_replace()` or `substr()` method